# Drupal CCK checkbox edit in views

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-views, cck

I'm running D6.22 with Views 2.12.  I use Views to create a "search / manage content" page for my site editors.

Is there a way, within Views, to show a CCK checkbox, and allow someone to select / unselect the checkbox from the View?  I'd like for my client to be able to see a list of all pages, and change the CCK checkbox for these pages without having to go to node/xxx/edit for each page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Views Bulk Operations (VBO)](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) , So select Style: Bulk Operations under "Basic settings" in views admin pane. then set settings of the style(by pressing gear wheel icon):
there is an option named "Modify node fields" at the end of "Selected operations:" now select the defined field(checkbox or somethings else) as Display fields.